# How to combine objects to array without removing duplicates in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, merge

I have 3 objects and I want them to combine into 1 array. There are duplicate property names in objects, but I want them too (with renames property name). How can I do that?

```
$object1 = {
    "id": "10",
    "unit_number": "12565"
},
$object2 = {
    "id": "20",
    "full_name": "Lorem Ipsm"
},
$object3 = {
    "id": "30",
    "phone": "123456789"
}
```

I want the output like,

```
array = (
    "id1" => "10",
    "unit_number" => "12565",
    "id2" => "20",
    "full_name" => "Lorem Ipsm",
    "id3" => "30",
    "phone" => "123456789"
);
```

I have tried to assign them to one array like,

```
$arr = array();
$arr['obj1'] = $object1;
$arr['obj2'] = $object2;
$arr['obj3'] = $object3;
```

Now I thought of doing a foreach, but I am stuck. My actual object is too big. So there are many duplicates. Not just this one.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Yes. Tried to assign to one array and do a looping. But stuck. See updated question.

Comment: is id the only element that is being duplicated ??

Comment: No. It may vary dynamically :( My actual objects are too big.

Comment: How about a sane approach and making an **array of `id`s**, instead of `id1`, `id2` etc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this using below code,

```
$object1 =  (object) ['id' => '10',  "unit_number"=> "12565", "name" => 'Test name'];

$object2 = (object) ['id' => '20',  "full_name"=> "Lorem Ipsm"];

$object3 = (object) ['id' => '30',  "phone"=> "123456789", "name" => "test name 1"];

$array1 = (array) $object1;
$array2 = (array) $object2;
$array3 = (array) $object3;

function array_merge_dup_keys() {
  $arrays = func_get_args();
  $data = array();
  foreach ($arrays as $a) {
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
      $key1 = check_key_exists($k,$data);   
      $data[$key1] = $v;
    }
  }
  return $data;
}

function check_key_exists($key,$array,$loop_count=1)
{  
    if(array_key_exists ( $key , $array ))
        {   
            $val = explode('_',$key);
            $count = isset($val[1]) ? $val[1] : $loop_count;
            $start_key = isset($val[0]) ? $val[0] : $key;
            $key = $start_key.'_'.$loop_count; 
            $key = check_key_exists($key,$array,$count+1);
        }
    return $key;
}

$data = array_merge_dup_keys($array1 ,$array2,$array3);
```

The output ($data) of above code will be,

```
Array
(
    [id] => 10
    [unit_number] => 12565
    [name] => Test name
    [id_1] => 20
    [full_name] => Lorem Ipsm
    [id_2] => 30
    [phone] => 123456789
    [name_1] => test name 1
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe something like this? (untested, possible typos/syntax errors...)

```
// this looks like json, not PHP
// "object1": {
//    "id": "10",
//    "unit_number": "12565"
// },
// "object2": {
//    "id": "20",
//    "full_name": "Lorem Ipsm"
// },
// "object3": {
//    "id": "30",
//    "phone": "123456789"
//  }

// here is a php array for that data
$objArray = array(
  "object1" => array( "id"=>"10", "unit_number"=>"12565"),
  "object2" => array( "id"=>"20", "full_name"=>"Lorem Ipsm"),
  "object3" => array( "id"=>"30", "phone"=>"123456789")
);
$newArray = array();
foreach( $objArray as $key=>$value)
{
  // the the id "append"
  $idAppend = substr($key, strlen("object"));

  foreach($value as $subkey=>$subvalue)
  {
    $newkey = $subkey;
    if ( strcmp($subkey, "id") == 0 ) // it is the id string
    {
      $newkey = $subkey.$idAppend;
    }

    $newArray[$newkey] = $subvalue;
  }
}
```